# Containing second column with products all in order

Tags: html, css

I have a list of products, once they continue down the page and have reached passed the sidebar it will then start appearing all the way from the left side of the page. I need the products to continue to stay in their to the right as they start off like.

I've given the sidebar and products container a col-1, col-2 class and each has the following:

```
    .col-1 {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.col-2 {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I've put in clear:both after the floats too in the css. I would post this on jsfiddle but as im using twitter bootstrap elements, best to just link my site here:

http://jordancharters.co.uk/dev/test1/products.php

*update - i need to keep width and height as AUTO as i will be using this class multiple times on other pages.

Comment: Did you give my suggestion a shot? See below…

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-left` to the `.col-2` equal to `.col-1`'s width:

```
.col-2 {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 220px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the quickest fix if you know the width of first column.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your left column is floated left; that means that everything to the right from it will wrap that column. Look at this image.[image]

You can try to define a class for those 2 columns, for example

```
.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Then give a width (or max-width) to each:

```
.col-1{
  max-width: 300px;
  // or width: 33%;
}
.col-2{
  max-width: 660px;
  //or width: 66%;
}
```

I know you don't want to apply width to it, but this a proper way to get what you want without some ugly hacks.
And it is also a good practice to get those columns inside some kind of `.container` to give it clearfix to avoid 0-height issues:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col col-1">
    Your column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col col-2">
    Your column 2
  </div>

</div>

.container:before,
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.container:after {
    clear: both;
}
.container {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

Clearfix methods you can find here and anywhere else:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Easy: Just add `overflow: hidden;` to .col-2:

```
.col-1 {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.col-2 {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```